How do I delete all vertices above a line with Geometry Nodes?
I am learning to use Geometry Nodes. I have a triangulated grid with corner vertices at $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, $(1, 1, 0)$, and $(0, 1, 0)$. I want to delete all vertices (and faces and edges) above the line $y = 1 − x$. What is the simplest way to do this?

My end-goal is to have a triangle mesh with vertices at $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, and $(0, 1, 0)$, and a user-input integer $n$ greater than or equal to one, with the main triangle subdivided into similar triangles such that:

each side of the subdivided mesh is composed of $n$ edges, and
each internal edge is parallel to one of the original three sides (or, equivalently, the internal angles of all new, smaller triangles are identical to the internal angles of the original, larger triangle).

The "Subdivide Mesh" node doesn't do what I want, as it divides each side of the main triangle into $2^n$ edges and divides the triangle itself into quads with internal edges that are not parallel to the boundary edges. I've looked through the other node options and the documentation, but I haven't seen any single node that seems like it will work, so I'm trying to work out the simplest combination that achieves my goal. If there is a better way than my current subdivide-a-grid-and-delete-half-of-it approach, I'd love to see it.
This question has several answers which give node setups that are enormously complicated, with a focus on subdividing arbitrary 3D meshes by powers of two. I just want to subdivide a single flat triangle linearly instead of exponentially.

This? https://imgur.com/a/tDbiyV7  If you rearrange your equation, that's Delete   Selection  (X+Y > 1)

Maybe related How to make an Equilateral Triangle Grid with Geometry Nodes?

BTW, there's nothing that stops you from making a sketch of what is the end result you want to achieve - or modelling manually the end result to show what you want to get in geonodes.

The nodes (1,2,3) of the following answer are doing exactly what you want to produce the lower triangle : GN: How to smooth out jagged edges after deleting geometry?.

Comments from @RobinBetts and @StefLAncien led me to a solution:

